# Could you simplify this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you simplify this sentencd. I can't get the meaning :

" ...every one of them fell ill because he had lost that which the living religions of every age have given to their followers, and none of them has been really healed who did not regain his religious outlook."

I have problem with **that which ...** in the first part of the sentence. And in the second part with ... heald **who** did not ...

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you encounter this sentence?

Comment: In a book entitled " HOW TO STOP WORRYING AND START LIVING" DALE CARNEGE.

Comment: You haven't quoted a complete sentence.

Comment: Sorry, but I've quoted what I didn't understand. The next time I'll pay more attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the writer, **religions have always given their followers something**, but s/he doesn't tells us what it is. (Perhaps it is explained earlier in the book.) The word "that" is used to mean 'that thing'.

**They all fell ill because they had lost that thing which was given to them by religion. And only those people who regained their religious outlook have been really healed.**

To heal means *to make well again*, or *to make healthy*.

Notice that "Everyone of them fell ill" is in the past tense but "none of them has been really healed" is in the present perfect tense. It means "people who did not regain their religious outlook have **still** (even today) not been healed."

Comment: Got it thank you Old Brixtonian.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, it simply says this:

> They all fell ill because they lost their religion. Those who never regained their religion remained ill.

It's a bit more nuanced than that, but that's the basic sentiment.

Comment: Thank you Jason Bassford. Got it.